# Adverbial phrase across multiple sentences

Tags: usage, adverbial-phrases, academic-writing

Consider the following toy example:

> Chess is a board game. **More precisely**, there are 2 players. There is an 8 by 8 grid. There are 6 kinds of pieces. There are...

It seems to me that the scope of *more precisely* should cover the multiple sentences that follow it, but not just *there are 2 players*. I wish I could write something like this:

> Chess is a board game. **More precisely**: {There are 2 players. There is an 8 by 8 grid. There are 6 kinds of pieces. There are...}

This problem sometimes bothers me, especially when I am writing academic articles, where a term has two different discriptions, one is more concise, and the other often in multiple simple sentences, and I want to connect the first concise description of the term with its multi-sentence explanantion by an adverbial phrase such as *more precisely*. **What are some good ways I can do this?**

I know that the toy example is not a good illustration of the above, but I can't think of an example at hand that is not too technical. Something similar would be this: First define an adjective *chessy* to mean every property of the chess game. Then the example becomes:

> Chess is a chessy game. **More precisely**, there are 2 players. There is an 8 by 8 grid. There are 6 kinds of pieces. There are...

Some simple (but not satisfactory) workarounds I can think of are:

- using point form
- using a descriptive sentence after the adverbial phrase:

> Chess is a chessy game. **More precisely, the following properties hold for the chess game.** There are 2 players. There is an 8 by 8 grid. There are...

Comment: To me, the obvious solution would be to make it all one sentence: _More precisely, a game for two players, played on an 8x8 grid with six kinds of pieces..._

Comment: @KateBunting That's what maybe works for this specific example, but often it just is much more natural to write it in multiple sentences.

Comment: What is "point form"? Does that mean bullet points? If so, why do you find it unsatisfactory?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, I do mean bullet points. It is sometimes unsatisfactory because it takes a lot of space, and is usually used for very important things. Imagine if you just want to mention some not-so-related examples in a paragraph (to give pointers to readers for example). You can't use bullet points for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just use ***semicolons*** instead of periods to separate the assertions following ***more precisely***.

That way, the orthography more explicitly indicates a "whole sentence" adverbial usage applying to *all* clauses within that "extended" sentence.

Bear in mind that this is purely a matter of "finnicky" orthography. There's no equivalent in *real* (spoken) English, so imho that means it's not very important anyway.